# mod_rewrite not making my url pretty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this might be a simple fix but I cannot figure it out.

I have my .htaccess file in folder called videos that is in my root file.

I wrote this rewrite mod:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^videos/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ vid.php?=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

For some reason my url still comes up like this:

```
http://localhost/fap2/videos/vid.php?id=1
```

It does not replace that ?id=1 with just the number 1 like vid.php/1

---

Also since that vid.php?id=1 is from a href on index.php, and It looks like this:

```
<a href="videos/vid.php?id=' . $tag["video_tag"] .'">
```

my pages are based on that id. Can I somehow show the id category name instead of a numer so for example that vid.php?id=1 be that actual name vid.php/category1 or is that based on changing that a href tag?

Thank you

Comment: What is your document root? fap2?

Comment: Also do your current rules work with path like `http://example.com/videos/1234`?

Comment: @PanamaJack yes fap2

Comment: @PanamaJack i tried it but it does not work like that only the original way.

Comment: It seems to be like fap2 is a subfolder of your real URL. Try adding a rewritebase after RewriteEngine On.  `RewriteBase /fap2/`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /fap2/
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]+) vid.php?id=$1 [L]
```